# Comparing two columns and extracting the entire row data in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison

The names from a column in sheet1 has to be compared with names from a column in sheet2, and the if a name matches, the entire row data of that particular name from sheet2 has to be displayed in sheet1 without overriding the existing data in sheet1.

Comment: See if this helps :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193978/how-to-compare-two-columns-in-excel-from-different-sheets-and-copy-values-from

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this.  A Query can start from an existing Excel table.

I would start one Query based on sheet2.  I would Merge the data from sheet1 on the name column, and select the Only include matching rows check box.

Then I would start a 2nd Query based on sheet1, and Append the results of the 1st Query. I would deliver the results to a new Excel Table.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/combine-multiple-queries-HA103993872.aspx